# Как прочитать поврежденный файл?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как прочитать битый файл.
Перебираю по байтово  весь файл, а в середине натыкаюсь на 0 байт.  Во всех доках перебор побайтовый выглядит так:

```
while(bite !=-1)
```

но когда файлик битый я ловлю 0 и попадаю в инфинити луп, и Vim так же. А можно как нить этот байт проскочить и попытаться прочитать дальше? Или я бред спрашиваю?

Comment: есть программки которые могут читать файлы до какогото уровня повреждения...

Comment: RandomAccessFile - походу то что нужно. Изучаю :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Читайте не как поток, а через [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Причем надо читать не до `read()==-1` или `IOException()`, а пока не будет достигнут `RandomAccessFile.length()` игнорируя все ошибки.

Comment: Спасиииибооо большущеее!!!

Comment: На здоровье...